# Problem with textures in opengl 3.3 (Program running on intel hd but not in Nvidia 1050 ti)

Tags: c++, opengl

I am making a program that has a room, with various objects inside it. To do it i use OpenGL version 3.3.
To light the room i am using a point light in the middle of the room and a cube shadow map to create the shadows. (To create the shadow cube map i make use of a geometry shader but i think this doesn't have to do with the problem)

My problem is that in my laptop that has an intel Hd graphics GPU or even in my desktop using the core's intel gpu, everything works perfectly, but when i use my nvidia 1050ti everything disappears and all i can see is the skybox which is around the room. 
This is the result when using the Nvidia

[image]

and this is how it should look

[image]

I made some tests to find what is causing the problem. I tried using the shadow cube map instead of the skybox's cube map to see if the shadow cube map texture was created successfully and the result was right. I also tried in my fragment shader to set fragment color as red when there is no shadow in an area and green where these should be shadow and the result is the following.

[image]

I also tried to render the scene without taking the shadows into account (i calculate the shadow factor) and it works just fine (of course without the shadows) this is the result

[image]

I've narrowed the problem down to the fragment shader

Because not all my items have a texture i have a uniform variable that tests whether there is texture and if so it samples it.

```
vec4 mlpier =vec4(1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0);
if (texequip==1){
    mlpier = vec4(texture(diffuseColorSampler,vertex_UV).rgb,1.0);
}
```

My shadow calculating functions is

```
float ShadowCalculation(vec3 vertex_pos_world){

    // get vector between fragment position and light position
    vec3 fragToLight = vertex_pos_world - light.lightPosition_worldspace;

    // use the light to fragment vector to sample from the depth map    
    float closestDepth = texture(depthMap, fragToLight).r;

    // it is currently in linear range between [0,1]. Re-transform back to original value
    closestDepth *= farplane;

    // now get current linear depth as the length between the fragment and light position
    float currentDepth = length(fragToLight);

    // now test for shadows
    float bias = 0.05; 
    float shadow = (currentDepth-bias) < closestDepth ? 1.0 : 0.0;

    return shadow;
}
```

and finally the way i calculate the fragment color is

```
fragment_color = vec4(Ia + shadow_factor * ( Id * light.power / distance_sq + Is * light.power / distance_sq),1.0) * mlpier;
```

When i don't multiply with the mlpier the scene is rendered with correct shadows but without the without the textures

```
fragment_color = vec4(Ia + shadow_factor * ( Id * light.power / distance_sq + Is * light.power / distance_sq),1.0);
```

and when i dont multiply with the shadow_factor the scene is rendered with correct textures but without shadows (as expected).

```
fragment_color = vec4(Ia +  ( Id * light.power / distance_sq + Is * light.power / distance_sq),1.0)* mlpier;
```

but what i want to do is keep both the shadows and the textures.

Update:

I am adding the whole vertex and fragment shader code

-> vertex shader

```
#version 330 core

// construct input layout for the corresponding attributes
// (vertexPosition_modelspace, vertexNormal_modelspace, vertexUV)
layout(location = 0) in vec3 vertexPosition_modelspace;
layout(location = 1) in vec3 vertexNormal_modelspace;
layout(location = 2) in vec2 vertexUV;

// Output variables (position_modelspace, normal_modelspace and UV coordinates), 
// that will be interpolated for each fragment
out vec3 vertex_position_modelspace;
out vec3 vertex_normal_modelspace;
out vec2 vertex_UV;
out vec4 st_shadow;

// uniforms (P, V, M)
uniform mat4 P;
uniform mat4 V;
uniform mat4 M;
uniform mat4 lightP;
uniform mat4 lightV;

void main()
{
    // Output position of the vertex, in clip space : MVP * position
    gl_Position =  P * V * M * vec4(vertexPosition_modelspace, 1);

    //  propagate the position of the vertex to fragment shader
    vertex_position_modelspace = vertexPosition_modelspace;

    // propagate the normal of the vertex to fragment shader
    vertex_normal_modelspace = vertexNormal_modelspace; 

    // propagate the UV coordinates   
    vertex_UV = vertexUV;


    // create a shadow map texture coordinate by backwards-ising the position.
    vec4 vertex_position_worldspace = M * vec4(vertex_position_modelspace,1.0);
    st_shadow = lightP * lightV * vertex_position_worldspace;
    st_shadow.xyz /= st_shadow.w;
    st_shadow.xyz += vec3(1.0,1.0,1.0);
    st_shadow.xyz *= 0.5;
}
```

-> fragment shader

```
#version 330 core

// interpolated values from the vertex shaders (vertex_position_modelspace, 
// vertex_normal_modelspace and vertex_UV coordinates)
in vec3 vertex_position_modelspace;
in vec3 vertex_normal_modelspace;
in vec2 vertex_UV;
in vec4 st_shadow;

// uniform variables (lightPosition_worldspace, V, M)

uniform vec3 light_position_worldspace;
uniform mat4 V;
uniform mat4 M;
uniform int texequip;
uniform float farplane;

// (diffuseColorSampler, specularColorSampler)
uniform sampler2D diffuseColorSampler;
uniform sampler2D texturemapSampler;
uniform sampler2D depth_map;
uniform samplerCube depthMap;

// Phong
// light properties
struct Light {
    vec3 La;
    vec3 Ld;
    vec3 Ls;
    vec3 lightPosition_worldspace;
    float power;
};
uniform Light light;

// materials
struct Material {
    vec3 Ka;
    vec3 Kd;
    vec3 Ks;
    float Ns;
    sampler2D texKa;
    sampler2D texKd;
    sampler2D texKs;
    sampler2D texNs;
};
uniform Material mtl;



// output data
out vec4 fragment_color;

// for point light - cube shadow mapping
float ShadowCalculation(vec3 vertex_pos_world){

    // get vector between fragment position and light position
    vec3 fragToLight = vertex_pos_world - light.lightPosition_worldspace;

    // use the light to fragment vector to sample from the depth map    
    float closestDepth = texture(depthMap, fragToLight).r;

    // it is currently in linear range between [0,1]. Re-transform back to original value
    closestDepth *= farplane;

    // now get current linear depth as the length between the fragment and light position
    float currentDepth = length(fragToLight);

    // now test for shadows
    float bias = 0.05; 
    float shadow = (currentDepth-bias) < closestDepth ? 1.0 : 0.0;


    return shadow;

}


void phong();

void main(){
    phong();
}


void phong() {
    vec3 _Ks = mtl.Ks;
    vec3 _Kd = mtl.Kd;
    vec3 _Ka = mtl.Ka;
    float _Ns = mtl.Ns;
    // use texture for materials
    if (_Ka.r < 0.0) _Ka = vec3(texture(mtl.texKa, vertex_UV).rgb);
    if (_Kd.r < 0.0) _Kd = vec3(texture(mtl.texKd, vertex_UV).rgb);
    if (_Ks.r < 0.0) _Ks = vec3(texture(mtl.texKs, vertex_UV).rgb);
    if (_Ns < 0.0) _Ns = texture(mtl.texNs, vertex_UV).r;



    vec3 vertex_position_worldspace = vec3(M * vec4(vertex_position_modelspace,1.0));
    vec3 vertex_position_cameraspace = vec3(V * vec4(vertex_position_worldspace,1.0));
    vec3 vertex_normal_cameraspace = vec3(V * M * vec4(vertex_normal_modelspace,0.0));

    // model ambient intensity (Ia)
    vec3 Ia = light.La * _Ka;

    // model diffuse intensity (Id)
    vec3 N = normalize(vertex_normal_cameraspace);
    vec3 L = normalize((V * vec4(light.lightPosition_worldspace, 1)).xyz
    - vertex_position_cameraspace);
    float cosTheta = clamp(dot(L, N), 0, 1);
    vec3 Id = light.Ld * _Kd * cosTheta;

    // model specular intensity (Is)
    vec3 R = reflect(-L, N);
    vec3 E = normalize(- vertex_position_cameraspace);
    float cosAlpha = clamp(dot(E, R), 0, 1);
    float specular_factor = pow(cosAlpha, _Ns);
    vec3 Is = light.Ls * _Ks * specular_factor;

    //model the light distance effect
    float distance = length(light.lightPosition_worldspace
    - vertex_position_worldspace);
    float distance_sq = distance * distance;

    // check if the object has a texture or not
    vec4 mlpier =vec4(1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0);
    if (texequip==1){
        mlpier = vec4(texture(diffuseColorSampler,vertex_UV).rgb,1.0);
    }

    // calculating the shadow factor
    float shadow_factor = ShadowCalculation(vertex_position_worldspace);

    // final fragment color
    fragment_color = vec4(Ia +shadow_factor * ( Id * light.power /     distance_sq + Is * light.power / distance_sq),1.0) * mlpier;
}
```

Comment: "*I've narrowed the problem down to the fragment shader*" Unless you have turned on blending, it *can't* be the fragment shader (or at least not the way you mean). Why? Because the fragment shader cannot force fragments to not appear without an explicit `discard`. If the FS doesn't write to an output, or writes incorrect values to that output, *some value* will still appear. The fact that you're getting no rendering tells me that you're probably getting an OpenGL error somewhere when you try to render. So maybe your shader failed to compile, but you didn't check.

Comment: Of course, since you didn't provide an [mcve], there's no way for anyone else to know if you checked or not, or whether your shader should compile/link or not.

Comment: I think that because both the cube map and the texture work seperatelly the problem is at the point where i combine them. I cannot show my entire code because it is over 1000 lines and it consists of multiple files. Although if there is a part of the code that would be helpful to show i would gladly upload it

Comment: @GiannhsRomanelhs Are you sure the shader is compiled/linked on **nVidia** ? My bet is that Intel is ignoring some issue that nVidia is not hence not compiled/linked shader on nVidia using fixed function instead which has most likely different locations then yours ... Other possibility is your uniform got optimized out...  you need to check the GLSL logs and get uniform location ... Anyway without MCVE we can only guess

Comment: As far as I 've seen I don't get any compiling nor linking errors. But what seems odd to me is that when I use them sepperatly everything works. Also, when I use them separately I still calculate the shadow factor but I just skip it in the last line (As I mentioned above ). And even if there was a problem with the shadow cube map values, the shadow calculation function just returns a float number. (1.0 or 0.0) and I have checked that it works. I have no problem sending more of my code, I just don't know which parts.

Comment: @GiannhsRomanelhs the multiplication itself might use some casting between types which might be the problem ... Ideally post the whole shaders so we can see if they compile and what is the GLSL logs if not. However without MCVE I am afraid that is the max we can do ... also what drivers you got for the nVidia ... Windows usually force wrong driver for gfx cards (and not just for them) these days ... Its better to install vendor driver manually instead of using windows update. Also to notify user `nick` (present in the thread) add `@nick` to your comment

Comment: I just added the code of the shader files. If you need any other part of the code i can add it. I think to update the drivers i used the default nvidia program if thats what you mean. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Your source code is still far away from being an MCVE. Your complete OpenGL state at the time of the draw call is totally unknown. For example, which texture units are you using for the four different textures? Also, as NicolBolas already mentioned, is blending on or off? Your example is not _complete_, but it is at the same time also not _minimal_. You do not need a whole scene to demonstrate the issue, a single triangle is probably enough, and also a much simpler shader.

Comment: I added the shaders because Spektre asked me to. Blending is enabled. The textures I bind work perfectly on their own, the problem comes when combined with shading. I know it is not an MCVE, if so I can delete the question if you want me to

Comment: @GiannhsRomanelhs the shaders are compiled cleanly on mine Win7 x64 nVidia GTX550 Ti driver: 388.71 GL ver: 4.6.0 so I would check the drivers first ...